# How to replace a named column's values to NA

Tags: r

I have a dataframe. Both the rows and columns are labeled. I want to replace a column's - say named as *abc* - values to `NA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(6,7,8))
df$a <- NA
df
   a b
1 NA 6
2 NA 7
3 NA 8
```

Double-check that it's really NA:

```
is.na(df$a)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Another way of setting a column to NA:

```
is.na(df$a) <- df$a
df
   a b
1 NA 6
2 NA 7
3 NA 8
```